# Wildcard cert on Synology NAS

Tags: nas, ssl-certificate, letsencrypt, synology-diskstation

I'm running Synology DSM 6.2.2-24922 Update 4 and I wish to setup a wildcard cert with Let's Encrypt. It has been over a year since I've tried this and that time it didn't go so well. I can remember I tried the acme.sh script but never really got it working for some reason. What's the status for this now a year later? I was hoping Synology had added wildcard support by now but it does not seem so? Strangely I can't find much info about this when googling the subject. Pretty much all hits are around jan-feb 2019 and about all the different workarounds. But why won't Synology fix this? Is there a really good reason for not doing it?

If not full support for all kinds of wildcard-certs they could at least add support for the most basic one: "*.domain.com" plus the naked domain.

**Update**:

I've given this a new try but failing on the last step it seems. When running the script I get a write permission denied at the end. I'm not running with sudo because that was the recommended way of doing this. I went on to try and copy the cert manually but when looking in the folder it said it put the certs in they are not there...

```
[Tue Feb 11 11:16:47 CET 2020] Your cert is in  /var/services/homes/admin/.acme.sh/*.mydomain.com/*.mydomain.com.cer
[Tue Feb 11 11:16:47 CET 2020] Your cert key is in  /var/services/homes/admin/.acme.sh/*.mydomain.com/*.mydomain.com.key
[Tue Feb 11 11:16:47 CET 2020] The intermediate CA cert is in  /var/services/homes/admin/.acme.sh/*.mydomain.com/ca.cer
[Tue Feb 11 11:16:47 CET 2020] And the full chain certs is there:  /var/services/homes/admin/.acme.sh/*.mydomain.com/fullchain.cer
[Tue Feb 11 11:16:47 CET 2020] Installing cert to:/usr/syno/etc/certificate/_archive/gc8oWR/cert.pem
./acme.sh: line 5236: /usr/syno/etc/certificate/_archive/gc5oWS/cert.pem: Permission denied
```

Comment: Did you setup the proper DNS entries for let's encrypt? [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/) doesn't support wildcard certificates with every challenge type.

Comment: Yes I did add the challange-record but if I'm not remembering this wrong I didn't get the cron-job to "stick" with Synology. I'll have to dig into this again it seems. I was just hoping there was a simpler solution...

Comment: If you want to use Let's Encrypt with a wildcard certificate you will have to follow that approach. You can choose a [number of clients](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/) to do so. I can't say what works on a synology or doesn't.

Comment: In any case I got it working now by running with sudo and changing the order of the domains in the command to have the naked domain first and the wildcard second.